# Html site keeps refreshing and not giving output when i clicked button for submitting

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a site which i want to enter values into form fields, and then output some results however Ive finished the Website UI and moving onto the javascript to do the actual calculations however, when i press the button my website just keeps refreshing and erasing the values and my function doesn't console.log the values but iam not getting errors.
I am completely new to javascript so any help would be great. If you need any further code please ask me.

(the css is done with bulma)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Uni Weight Grade Calculator</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.ico">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css"/>
    <script
      defer
      src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js">
    </script>
  </head>

<body>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="container is-centered is-mobile">
            <div class="content has-text-centered">
                <h1>Weighted Average Calculator</h1>
                <p>
                    This Simple Grade Calculator will determine your average grade for your assignments,
                    end of year grade or end of university grade.
                    <br>
                    The weighted average simply takes into account how much each course is worth when calculating the average.
                    <br>
                    This calculator can also be used to calculate any weighted average, not just courses.
                    <br><br><br>
                </p>
                </div>

                <div class="columns is-centered">
                <div class="column is-three-quarters">

                    <div class="card">

                        <div class="columns is-gapless is-multiline is-mobile">
                            <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered is-size-5">
                                <h1 class="has-text-weight-semibold">The Entry</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered is-size-5">
                                <h1 class="has-text-weight-semibold">Grade (%)</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered is-size-5">
                                <h1 class="has-text-weight-semibold">Weight (Credits)</h1>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                    <div class="card-content">
                        <form id="grade-form">
                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">1</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right ">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade1" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit1" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">2</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade2" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit2" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">3</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade3" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit3" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">4</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade4" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit4" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">5</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade5" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit5" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">6</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade6" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit6" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">7</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade7" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit7" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">8</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade8" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit8" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control">
                            <button  id="submit" class="button is-large is-fullwidth is-primary is-outlined">
                            Calculate
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- RESULTS -->
    <section class="section is-centered is-mobile"> 
        <h1 class="title has-text-centered">Calculated Results</h1>
        <div class="columns is-multiline is-centered">
        
            <div class="column is-12-tablet is-6-desktop is-3-widescreen ">
                <div class="notification is-success is-light has-text">
                <p id="monthlyPayment" class="title is-1"><i class="fa fa-percentage"></i></p>
                <p class="subtitle is-4">Average Grade</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-12-tablet is-6-desktop is-3-widescreen">
                <div class="notification is-link is-light has-text">
                <p id="totalInterest" class="title is-1"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></p>
                <p class="subtitle is-4">Formal Grade</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


</body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
// Check if user has entered any values and pressed submit
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(){
    calculateResults;
};

// Grade calculation function
function calculateResults(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const UIgrade1 = document.getElementById("grade1").value(), UIcredit1 = document.getElementById("credit1").value();
    const UIgrade2 = document.getElementById("grade2").value(), UIcredit2 = document.getElementById("credit2").value();
    const UIgrade3 = document.getElementById("grade3").value(), UIcredit3 = document.getElementById("credit3").value();
    const UIgrade4 = document.getElementById("grade4").value(), UIcredit4 = document.getElementById("credit4").value();
    const UIgrade5 = document.getElementById("grade5").value(), UIcredit5 = document.getElementById("credit5").value();
    const UIgrade6 = document.getElementById("grade6").value(), UIcredit6 = document.getElementById("credit6").value();
    const UIgrade7 = document.getElementById("grade7").value(), UIcredit7 = document.getElementById("credit7").value();
    const UIgrade8 = document.getElementById("grade8").value(), UIcredit8 = document.getElementById("credit8").value();

    console.log(UIgrade1);
    console.log(UIcredit1);
}
```

Comment: `calculateResults;` you should call this function `calculateResults(e);`

Comment: This is not a [mcve]

Comment: @Jack doesnt seem to fix anything the site just refreshes and clears everything,including the console output

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Get the event parameter
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(e){
    calculateResults(e); // Call the function
};
```

Comment: this almost works, but i get this issue Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).value is not a function
    at calculateResults (index.js:10)
    at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.onclick (index.js:3)

Comment: `.value()` it should be `.value` it's just property